# Method to use existing project into newer one in Android

Tags: java, android

I tried to use one android project to another android project for this purpose I use

**Properties--->Build Path-->Project--->Add(Select the project then add it)
-->Order and Export--> select project**

But this gives the following error:

```
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gps_test_prt/com.example.gps_test_prt.GPS_prt_main}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.gps_test_prt.GPS_prt_main
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.gps_test_prt.GPS_prt_main
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
07-26 11:03:09.878: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  ... 11 more
```

`

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: use project as library

Comment: why not make 1 library project and reference the same in another

Answer (score 0):

It seems you class cannot be instantiated. This may be :

1. Visibility isn't public, or no public constructor
2. Activity not declared in the manifest of your using application
3. Android Dependencies or Android Private Libraries not exported in your library or final project

Answer (score 0):

Properties--->Android-->Add select the library project and if you are using ADT 22 check the Android Dependencies & Android Private Libraries in the Order&Export tab.